# Angular 2 Reactive Froms - bind a whole object at once

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning reactive forms in Angular 2 and I was wondering if it was possible to bind all object properties at once. Each guide I see show something like that :

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    event: this.fb.group({
        title: ['', Validators.required],
        location: ['', Validators.required]
    })
});
```

Then setting values like that :

```
this.form.setValue({
    name: object.name,
    event: object.event
});
```

For me, this is not something doable in real situation, because you often need to bind a lot of properties and defining them is not really convenient. And if the model change, you need to update it in both place.

So I tried this :

```
this.refundRecordForm = this.fb.group(new RefundRecord());
this.refundRecordForm.setValue(this.refundRecord);
```

But I got this error :

> Error: 
>           There are no form controls registered with this group yet.  If you're using ngModel,
>           you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout)

If I use `patchValue` instead of `setValue`, no errors but the form contains no controls.

I tried binding manually a few fields and it worked so my guess is that you can't bind the whole object at once.

So I'm wondering if it's possible. I'm very new to this so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
this.refundRecordForm = this.fb.group(new RefundRecord());
```

Wouldn't work unless RefundRecord is defined as a set of FormControls.

For reactive forms to work, you need to create a form group and associated FormControls. That's the meaning of the error message you are getting

You could try creating the form as you had it:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    event: this.fb.group({
        title: ['', Validators.required],
        location: ['', Validators.required]
    })
});
```

And then try assigning the values using your short cut syntax:

```
this.form.setValue(this.refundRecord);  // or .patchValue
```

I don't know if that would work, I didn't try it, so let us know how you do. Or you can build a plunker and we can give it a try.

You could also take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form Which shows how to build dynamic forms.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do here is just create one function that will return an `FormGroup` of your custom type. Everything else can stay the same.

For instance, change this:

```
this.refundRecordForm = this.fb.group(new RefundRecord());
this.refundRecordForm.setValue(this.refundRecord);
```

To this:

```
initRefundRecord(record: RefundRecord = new RefundRecord()): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        name: [record.name, Validators.required],
        event: this.fb.group({
            title: [record.event.title, Validators.required],
            location: [record.event.location, Validators.required]
        })
    });
}

// Set to new empty form group of refund record type
this.refundRecordForm = this.initRefundRecord();

// Update the value later
this.refundRecordForm.patchValue(this.refundRecord);
```

With that approach, if you want to create the form with pre-existing values you can simply do the following:

```
// Set to new prefilled form group of refund record type
this.refundRecordForm = this.initRefundRecord(preexistingRecord);

// Update the value later
this.refundRecordForm.patchValue(this.refundRecord);
```

And everything works the same. Now you only ever need to modify the form group that is created inside `initRefundRecord` when you want to add more fields and so on.